# Can TCP re-transmit a handshake when it’s lost in transport?

Tags: tcp

I saw a large number of failed connections between two hosts on my intranet (call them client and server).

Using netstat on both machines, I see corresponding port numbers where the server end is in SYN_RECV state and the client is in SYN_SENT.

My interpretation is that the server has responded to the client’s SYN with a SYN,ACK but this packet has been lost. The handshake is disrupted, the socket connection is in an incomplete state, and I see the client time out after 20-45 seconds.

My question is, does TCP offer a way for the server to re-transmit the SYN,ACK after some interval? Is this a good or bad idea?

More system details if relevant: both ends RHEL5, ssh succeeds, ping loses 100%, traceroute succeeds. Client is built on OpenOrb (Java), server is Mico (C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYN and FIN flags are considered part of the sequence space and are transmitted reliably (so, the answer to your immediate question is "yes, it does, by default").

However, I think you really want to dig a bit deeper, because:

If you have a large number of failed connections on the hosts on your intranet, this points to a problem in the network - normally you should have a low, if any, connections that are stuck in these states. Retransmissions would mean your connection will hiccup for 2,4,8,.. seconds (though not necessary - depends on the TCP stack. Nonetheless nothing pretty for the users).

I would advise to run tcpdump or wireshark on both hosts and trace where the loss of the packets happens - and fix it.

On older hardware, a frequent reason could be a duplex mismatch on some pair of the devices in the path (incorrectly autodetected, or incorrectly hardcoded). Some other reasons may be a problem with the driver, or a bad cable (not enough bad to cause complete outage, but bad enough to cause periodic blackouts).